# Most efficient way to "save" simple webapp's state to address bar /no backend

Tags: web-applications, urlencode

There is a class of simple webapps that "save" your work into to the address bar without the need for storing anything in the backend. Two examples:

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B%0A%0Avar%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B%0A)

[WebSequenceDiagrams.com](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/?lz=dGl0bGUgQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb24gU2VxdWVuY2UKCkFsaWNlLT5Cb2I6ABUQUmVxdWVzdApub3RlIHJpZ2h0IG9mIAAlBUJvYiB0aGlua3MgYWJvdXQgaXQKQm9iLT4ASgUANxNzcG9uc2UK&s=napkin)

What is the proper name for this functionality?

What is the most efficient way to do this? The TypeScript Playground literally copies the code into address bar but this is not very efficient. How about compressing the data?

**EDIT1:** My data is in JSON format.

**EDIT2:** I think my question boils down to what kind of compression can output URL safe characters.

**EDIT3:** The point of "saving" into URL as opposed to local storage is that user can copy/paste the state. Think of a TypeScript Playground snipped copied to SO answer.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is saving to the address bar a requirement? You could save off web application state to HTML5 local storage and still keep everything off the backend. This might be easier to work with, but your users wouldn't be able to, say, copy/paste their state from the address bar alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

**LZString.compressToBase64()**

compressToBase64 produces ASCII UTF-16 strings representing the original string encoded in Base64. Those can be safely transported outside the browser with a guarantee that none of the characters produced need to be URL-encoded. Can be decompressed with decompressFromBase64. This works by using only 6bits of storage per character. The strings produced are therefore 166% bigger than those produced by compress. It can still reduce significantly some JSON compressed objects.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can first compress the JSON string using http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html and then encode the compressed string using the built-in encodeURIComponent() function.

Download the library and specify it,

```
<script language="javascript" src="lz-string.js"></script>
```

Compress and encode your data,

```
var string = JSON.stringify({attr: "This is my compression test."});
alert("Size of sample is: " + string.length);

var compressed = LZString.compress(string);
alert("Size of compressed sample is: " + compressed.length);

var getParam = encodeURIComponent(compressed);
```

When decoding, decode with `decodeURIComponent()` first and then decompress it using `LZString.decompress(compressed)`.

Comment: Very close, the complete answer is to use LZString.compressToBase64

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple huffman compression and base64 to encode and decode some variables. I also used it to save some of my apps variables like page, pulldown selection, checkboxes. It has advantage to have it compressed in one place a.k.a state and also you can even save it to a file and use it as "breakpoint" or even create an archive. In ajax applications it gives also a browser history for the app and better desktop experience.  The possibilities are endless.  It state of the art for experienced developer but I didn't see many in the real life. BTW I saved it to a hidden field and for downloading I used a special user. It may be a risk to use it in the address bar only maybe for ajax history.

Comment: So I suppose there is a JS library for huffman compression? How does it differ for instance from LZV? can you tell me more about your implementation?

Comment: I'm not a compression expert but Huffman is a statistical compression it's not the same like lz family. I also tried a combination of move-to-front and burrow-wheeler algorithm for better compression to no avail. It depends on the data what is best for compression and speed. But it doesn't make sense to compress it clientside because you need to send it uncompressed? So, no JS! But you can try a range coder? It some of the best statistical compression.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. I want to do everything clientside, there is no backend at all. My webapp (JS based) generates data in JSON format that I would like to output to the address bar in URL safe format.

Comment: What do you want with all the data? Is this just something client-side? Anyway, you can find pseudocode for nearly everthing look in wikipedia. It exercise for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a hashing algorithm or any other URL hash technique to code your web application state in the URL.

But as others already said HTML5 offers better ways to save your application state. Here's [a good article about that](http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2011/10/must-know-url-hashtechniques-for-ajax-applications/).

Comment: The point of "saving" into URL as opposed to local storage is that user can copy/paste the state. Think of a TypeScript Playground snipped copied to SO answer.

Comment: But you can save the application state in the server with a unique id. Then every time someone sends a link with that id, you can recover the application state.

jsfiddle and many Copy-Paste sites like pastebin use that approach.